# What does 'statements of fact' mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In the sentence

> One fact which emerges from these considerations is that no obstacle should be placed in the way of thought and its expression, nor yet in the way of statements of fact,

what does the author, Bertrand Russell, mean by 'statements of fact'? And how does that differ from the meaning of 'expression of thought'?

Comment: This is better suited to the Philosophy site (https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/), since you're asking to have Bertrand Russell's definition of terms explained.

Comment: Thanks @JasonBassford. It's from _Political Ideals_. Nowhere in the book those terms are defined. Also I think the book was written for general reader.

Comment: I studied philosophy (and Russell briefly) a long time ago, and something tells me this is not a simple English question. :) I could say that "statements of fact" means "utterances of truth"—except that even though people believe false things, having those beliefs are, themselves, facts. So, context is extremely important. And I'm not confident enough in everything I just said to think of it as an accurate reply . . .

Comment: @JasonBassford, your doubt could be a result of your familiarity with philosophy!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is now crossposted to philosophy

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*This answer does not try to answer what Bertrand Russell meant directly - as this is something we cannot know without asking him. However, it will give the common-person understanding of these two phrases, which should give the context you need to research further.*

---

A [fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fact) is:

> a statement that is consistent with reality or can be proven with evidence. The usual test for a **statement of fact** is verifiability — that is, whether it can be demonstrated to correspond to experience

This definition is the common understanding of a fact. That is something which can be proven to be objectively true. For example, "The Earth is a planet", is verifiable and true.

Importantly, in regular speech a statement of fact is anything presented to be verifiable and true. Even if evidence proves the statement not to be factual - it is still valid to say it was presented as a "statement of fact". For example "all dogs are blue" is a statement of fact, and not an opinion - even though it is clearly not a fact.

*It's worth noting that there are philosophical debates on what constitutes a fact, and whether anything is truly verifiable. This may be something touched on in the work you are reading and is worth bearing in mind.*

---

An **expression of thought** is anything which expresses (conveys, or puts into concrete terms) a thought process. There is no criteria for this to be a fact, or a verifiable claim in any sense.

Expression of thought could simply be speech, writing, dancing or any way that a thought can be conveyed.

---

As such, in common understanding, an expression of thought may be anything that articulates a certain idea - while a statement of fact would be a verifiable claim that can be proven to be true (or a statement which that criteria is claimed to be applicable).

---

Based on this, my understanding of the quote would be that Bertrand Russel is advocating for freedom to be able to express any thoughts whatsoever, and make any claims that are factual (or believed to be) - without obstacles or consquences.